# Problema al cargar CSS en Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Hola estoy haciendo un curso y en el mismo explican como cargar una hoja de CSS por medio de los archivos style.css, index.php y function.php. El problema que tengo es que no aplica los estilos a la pagina. En el archivo style.css tengo la cabecera que define al theme (esto funciona y se lee bien). Los tres archivos estan en el directorio raiz del tema. Ya probe borrando cache del navegador. Ya revise si da errores pon consola y chat GPT me dice que el codigo es correcto. La otra funcion que esta dentro de fuction.php funciona bien. El tema esta activado desde la plataforma de WP e incluso funciona correctamente porque puedo hacer modificaciones. Pero no aplica el estilo de prueba del background-color. Dejo lo que tengo en cada archivo.
style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: Gym Fitness
Theme URI: 
Author: Juan Pablo De la torre Valdez
Author URI: http://twitter.com/codigoconjuan
Description: Theme Diseñado para el Gimnasio GymFitness
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: Gym, gimnasio, flexbox, css grid, mobile first
Text Domain: gymfitness
*/
body {
background-color: red;
}
```

function.php

```
<?php
function gymfitness_menus() {
register_nav_menus(array(
'menu-principal => __('Menu Principal', 'gymfitness')
));
}
add_action('init', 'gymfitness_menus');
function gymfitness_scripts_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '1.0.0');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gymfitness_scripts_style');
?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
>html <?php language_attributes();?>>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<?php wp_head();?>
</head>
<body>
<header clas="header">
<div class"contenedor barra-navegacion">
<div class="logo">
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/logo.svg" alt="logotipo">
</div>
<?php
$args=array(
'theme_location'=>'menu-principal,
'container'=>'nav',
'container_class'=>'menu_principal'
);
wp_nav_menu($args);
?>
</div>
</header>
<main>
<?php>
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
the_title();
the_content();
endwhile;
?>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

En el function en lugar de get_stylesheet_uri() tambien probe get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' y sigue sin funcionar. Si yo agrego manualmente la etiqueta link en el index.php asi

">
Si carga los estilos pero no se porque de la otra forma no. Tambien probe en la version de estilos poner 1.0 para que sea igual a la version del tema. No tengo ninguna dependencia en para los estilos por eso el array esta vacio. No tengo ningun plugin instalado en wp el proyecto esta casi totalmente en blanco porque estoy aprendiendo a crear temas. Todo el contenido de cada pagina se carga correctamente el unico problema que tengo es que no aplica el estilo que contiene el archivo style.css. Solo tengo en la ruta raiz del tema esos tres archivos. Estoy usando Laragon para el host local.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionar el problema. El error era que tenia nombrado mal un archivo. function.php debe tener como nombre functions.php, La primera función del archivo estaba funcionando porque la misma no dependía de una función que necesite el nombre del archivo correcto. Pero la función que carga los estilos es llamada por la función wp_head(). Esta necesita del archivo functions.php para poder leer esa función. El error no estaba en el codigo sino en el nombre del archivo.

Comment: Recuerda que no es buena practica usar el **functions.php**